# What's wrong with twig?

Tags: symfony, twig

This is my first steps in symfony 2.0, so please apologise a basic question. I try to extend automaticaly generated crud code. To postcontroller I've added:

```
   /**
     * Prints a Post entity.
     *
     * @Route("/print", name="post_print")
     * @Template()
     */
public function printAction()
    {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $entities = $em->getRepository('AcmeBlogBundle:Post')->findAll();
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($entities);
        echo "</pre>";
        return array('entities' => $entities);
    }
```

created print.html.twig:

```
<h1>Post list</h1>

<table class="records_list">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Polish</th>
            <th>English</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for entity in entities %}
        <tr>
            <td><a href="{{ path('post_show', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">{{ entity.id }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ entity.polish }}</td>
            <td>{{ entity.english }}</td>
            <td>{% if entity.date %}{{ entity.date|date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}{% endif%}</td>
            <td>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ path('post_show', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">show</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ path('post_edit', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">edit</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>

<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="{{ path('post_new') }}">
            Create a new entry
        </a>
    </li>
        <li>
        <a href="{{ path('post_print') }}">
            Drukuj
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and I'm getting:

> Variable "entity" does not exist in AcmeBlogBundle:Post:print.html.twig at line 7
>   500 Internal Server Error - Twig_Error_Runtime

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: I guess `print.twig.html` and `print.html.twig` is just a typpo..?

Comment: thx .. typpo in question here. My file is correct.

Comment: This looks like a bug. What version of twig do you use (look at your deps file)?

Comment: I found in /symfony/vendor/twig/lib/Twig/environment.php something like it:
`class Twig_Environment
{
    const VERSION = '1.1.2';`

Comment: Latest version is 1.3.0 . Edit your deps file then run `php bin/vendors install`

Comment: what is the name and where is located file with deps? I can't find it :/

Comment: I've cleared cache ... and now everything seems to be OK. Thx

Comment: Please move the solution to this problem to an answer and accept it.

Comment: What's wrong with descriptives questions titles ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've cleared cache ... and now everything seems to be OK.